# Postgres 9.5 how to support boolean gin index

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

Since `btree_gin` in 9.5 does not support boolean data type, how can I use boolean column as part of multi-column gin index?

Comment: Why do you think you need to include the boolean column in the index? Typically conditions on boolean columns don't reduce the number of rows enough to make the optimizer use the index. If you have highly skewed values (many `true` values vs. only  a few `false` - or the other way round) a partial index would make more sense.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am actually doing some migrate form another database which have boolean column indexed, and I want to keep the same index here. But partial index seems a better solution as you point out.

Comment: When migrating between different DBMS products it is very seldom a good idea to blindly apply everything from the "source" to the "target". Database products are very different and behave very different. And besides: I don't know of any other DBMS that has a "GIN" index, so why do you create one in Postgres?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Actually I have a field called `is_read` which indicates that an item is read or not read,  so there are both a lot of true and false rows. And I migrate from a sadly inactive database called `rethinkdb`

Comment: *"Typically conditions on boolean columns don't reduce the number of rows enough to make the optimizer use the index."* You'd be surprised, @a_horse_with_no_name.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall': then the second part of that sentence would be relevant "*if you have highly skewed values...*".

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I have a table where the ratio of False to True is about 2/1, no NULLs. I don't call that highly skewed, but it uses an index. (B-Tree index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, it's possible, but you need to index the `(is_read::int::bit)` expression (instead of the column directly). **But**: you would need to use this expression in your `WHERE` clauses, to make use of this index; i.e.:

```
WHERE is_read::int::bit = '1'
-- or
WHERE is_read::int::bit = '0'
-- or even
WHERE is_read::int::bit < '1' -- which is just an obfuscated version of "= '0'"
```

However, this will make your queries less readable. And maybe even slower (see later).

If you ever query for one value (i.e. `WHERE is_read` or `WHERE NOT is_read`, but not both), a [partial index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html) would be a better fit.

However, dropping the column from the index could make it (somewhat) more compact, which can even fasten your queries in some cases.

I advise you to test each of these methods on your actual data, or show us (in another, follow-up question) your queries you are concerned with.

Here is a comparison for the above cases with some fairly artificial data:
http://rextester.com/OWXUA55980

Comment: Very luck, currently I only need to filter `unread` rows, so partial index seems good to me.